# Selecting a subset of an array based on values in another array with upper and lower bounds

Tags: python, arrays, python-2.7, numpy

I have two arrays, and I want to select a section of one of them based on values of the other.  I know how to do this in a few lines, but I want to know if there is a neater way, in one line, to do this.  This is how I do it which is long and ugly.

```
lower = some_value; upper = another_value
a = [some numpy array]; b = [another numpy array]
b_select = []
for i in range(len(a)):
    if a[i] < lower or a[i] > upper:
        b_select.append(b[i])
```

So basically my question is, can I get b_select in one line, instead of the last 4 lines?

Any advice would be much appreciated.  For info I am doing this in Python 2.7.

Answer (score 8):

The stated problem is looking to select values that are outside the bounds set by lower and upper bounds. To solve it, we can use [`boolean indexing`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/arrays.indexing.html#boolean-array-indexing) -

```
b[(a < lower) | (a > upper)]
```

---

The other scenario to select within the lower and upper bounds, invert the process -

```
b[(a > lower) & (a < upper)]
```

To have inclusiveness on the bounds, replace `<`'s with `<=` and `>`'s with `>=`.

Answer (score 0):

Unless numpy has some strange arrays this should work:

```
b_select = [x for x in a if (x < lower or x > upper)]
```